# Avoid data resetting when toggling series

Tags: javascript, linechart, chart.js

In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zs99pw4L/) when you `toggle` a serie the others reset to their inital values, instead of adding new values to themselves.
How to avoid this behaviour?

Comment: By the way, you might want to refactor your fiddle and simplify it. Otherwise it's a bit difficult for other folk to answer unless they've seen all the previous questions  :-). Also, do repost the code in the question - people tend to skip over fiddle only questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the current state of the data for each series before blanking or resetting the corresponding dataset in enableCheck. Then use this saved state.

**Example for the SP dataset**

Initialization of the state (spData). I also initialize the dataset (SP)

```
var spData = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
var SP = {}
```

Saving the state (in enableCheck()) - I get the values from the actual data points

```
if (SP.data) currentChart.datasets.forEach(function (d) {
    if (d.label === 'My First dataset') {
        spData = d.points.map(function (e) {
            return e.value
        });
    }
})
```

Using this saved state (in enableCheck())

```
SP = {
    label: "My First dataset",
    fillColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
    strokeColor: "rgba(220,0,0,1)",
    pointColor: "rgba(220,0,0,1)",
    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
    pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,0,0,1)",
    data: spData
};
```

And if you want the new values to be inserted for the hidden series as well, update your data insertion statements in your setTimeout

```
var d = []
if (First) d.push(randomScalingFactor())
else {
    spData.shift()
    spData.push(randomScalingFactor())
}
if (Second) d.push(randomScalingFactor())
else {
    ncData.shift()
    ncData.push(randomScalingFactor())
}
if (Third) d.push(randomScalingFactor())
else {
    spaData.shift()
    spaData.push(randomScalingFactor())
}
```

Working fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Lsg37amf/

Comment: Very good! You are a real genius.
The only fault with this is that if I hide a series, wait for n-update, then re-show it this starts from last shown values.